# ERR! network. Cannot install the latest version of npm, yeoman, bower and grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, yeoman, bower

I've a problem with the installation for yeoman, bower, grunt and the latest npm version.

The latest version of NodeJS (0.12.2) is installed on my pc.
I have the npm version 2.7.4 but when I start the git bash in the nodejs folder and type "npm install npm" or "npm install npm@latest" then it gives an error message:

```
error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
error argv "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "npm@latest"
error node v0.12.2
error npm  v2.7.4
error code ETIMEDOUT
error errno ETIMEDOUT
error syscall connect
error network connect ETIMEDOUT
error network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
error network and is related to network connectivity.
error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
error network
error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

And the complete debug log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'npm@latest' ]
2 info using npm@2.7.4
3 info using node@v0.12.2
4 warn package.json nodejs@0.12.2 No description
5 warn package.json nodejs@0.12.2 No repository field.
6 warn package.json nodejs@0.12.2 No README data
7 silly cache add args [ 'npm@latest', null ]
8 verbose cache add spec npm@latest
9 silly cache add parsed spec { raw: 'npm@latest',
9 silly cache add   scope: null,
9 silly cache add   name: 'npm',
9 silly cache add   rawSpec: 'latest',
9 silly cache add   spec: 'latest',
9 silly cache add   type: 'tag' }
10 verbose addNamed npm@latest
11 silly addNamed semver.valid null
12 silly addNamed semver.validRange null
13 info addNameTag [ 'npm', 'latest' ]
14 silly mapToRegistry name npm
15 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
16 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
17 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
18 verbose addNameTag registry:https://registry.npmjs.org/npm not in flight; fetching
19 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
20 verbose request no auth needed
21 info attempt registry request try #1 at 09:30:04
22 verbose request id 6fa6dc64e92e52cc
23 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
24 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
25 info attempt registry request try #2 at 09:30:35
26 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
27 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
28 info attempt registry request try #3 at 09:31:56
29 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
30 verbose stack Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
30 verbose stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
30 verbose stack     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1000:19)
31 verbose cwd c:\Program Files\nodejs
```

I've read some threads with problems of nodejs and found an ability to set the http proxy. Is that the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem. To find out my proxy-server name on windows 7 I've opened command line of windows and type: `netsh winhttp show proxy`

Then I added these lines in the .npmrc data (path:C:\users\username)

```
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
strict-ssl=false
proxy=http://username:password@proxy.domain.com:8080/
https-proxy=http://username:password@proxy.domain.com:8080
```

It works fine :)